# Does the Sidekiq API not show all available queues?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq

My `sidekiq.yml` config file defines the following queues

```
---

:queues:
  - [high_priority, 2]
  - mailers
  - default
  - low_priority
```

When Sidekiq starts up with the app, the app log correctly shows that the queues were picked up

```
...
Booting Sidekiq 3.5.0 with redis options {:url=>"redis://localhost:6379/", :network_timeout=>3}
...
Starting processing, hit Ctrl-C to stop
{:queues=>["high_priority", "high_priority", "mailers", "default", "low_priority"], :labels=>[], ...
```

But when I try using the [Sidekiq API](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/API) to retrieve the list of queues from the `rails console`, I only see the `default` queue

```
> Sidekiq::Queue.all
=> [#<Sidekiq::Queue:0x000001061f4760 @name="default", @rname="queue:default">]
```

Any reason the API doesn't return all queues?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Queues aren't created in Redis until a job is pushed to them.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a specific reason for the lazy loading? I can imagine there's a use case for those trying to use the Sidekiq API to design custom dashboards and such to have that info eager loaded. Is that something you'd be open to having a pull request submitted for?

Comment: No specific reason.  At this point, the semantic is not up for change.  It's easy to create the queue manually if necessary.